# 2 Hit detection on enemys SDL c++

Tags: c++, sdl

Hey guys got this for a 2 hit collision in my SDL game, only works on the front row of enemys and sometimes it takes over the 'maxHit' varible. Not to sure why this is what i had so far: Collideswith() works well and this works with just one hit, just need a way to increment some sort of a counter for each enemy AKA alien in the array.

```
 int maxHit = 2;
 int hitCount = 0;

  // Detect collisions
  for(auto p : projectiles)
  {
    for(auto a : aliens)
    {
      if(p->CollidesWith(a) && hitCount == maxHit)
      {
        p->HandleCollision();
        a->HandleCollision();       
      }  
      if(p->CollidesWith(a) && hitCount != maxHit)
      {  
        ++hitCount; 
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Swap the loops
2. Declare `hitCount` inside the "aliens" loop

E.g:

```
for(auto a : aliens) 
{
    for(auto p : projectiles) 
    {
        int hitCount = 0;
        //...
    }
}
```

And you also might want to rephrase your if clause to state your intention more clearly (and to boost performance):

```
if(p->CollidesWith(a))
{
    if(hitCount == maxHit)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm tried that way. Now it just goes straight through and does not recognize  any of the hits.

Comment: Then something else is wrong...

Comment: If `hitCount` is declared in the loop which is run for each animation frame, then they will not accumulate over time.